# ReactJS state of parent to update only the child component and not the parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Lets pretend we have the following components.

`

```
const parent = () => {

const [item, setItem] = useState(true)

return (

 <div
   <div onHover={()=>setItem(!item)}> 
      ...
   </div>
   <Child item={item}/>
 </div>)
}

const Child = ({item}) => {

return (item?
  
  <div>
    <h1> Cool! <h1/>
  </div>
  : 
 <div>
   <h1> Not Cool! <h1/>
 </div>
}
```

`

The hover that happens on parent element, affects the render method of child.
In my case, every time I hover on the parent element both parent and child re-renders. I wanna implement such as only the child re-renders.

What would be the best approach to this ?

Comment: May i ask why? Rendering both is the standard way to do this in react.

Comment: @NicholasTower My app is a widget and onMouseEnter I want the close button to show and onMouseLeave to hide. I don't want my whole app re-rendering for such minimal reason as it consists of hundreds of components.